# how can i add data to this object in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

on the client side, when you open the socket it will send this message:

```
 socket.onopen = function(event) {
 var jsonstring = JSON.stringify({"type":"join", "id":myStorage.username});
  socket.send(jsonstring);
};
```

on the server side we have an object called clientMessages, but i can't seem to tell if any data is getting added to it. additionally, it needs to somehow hold all the active users on the server.

```
    var clientMessages = {};

socket.on("message", function (data) {
  var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    if (parsed.type === "join") {
        var jsonstringy = JSON.stringify({ type: "history", value: clientMessages});
         socket.send(jsonstringy);

      clientMessages[parsed.id] = [parsed];      
    } else if (parsed.type === "leave") {
        delete clientMessages[parsed.id];          
    } else {       
    clientMessages[parsed.id].push(parsed);
     }
});
```

Comment: you want know only count of all users ? then add a simple var adn increment/decrement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `console.log(clientMessages)` every time you get a message to check it, but definitely this way should be ok. I do not see any problem there.

EDIT:
Ok i saw the source code, `var clientMessages = {};`is inside `wss.on('connec...`this means that everytime someone connects it will reset that variable. you should move the `var clientMessages = {};` above that `wss.on('..`

basically you will end up with something like this

```
var clientMessages = {}; //line 20
wss.on("connection", function (socket) { //line 21 not edited
```

Comment: so if i have that log statement, as new people join we see: 
{ charlie: [ { type: 'join', id: 'charlie' } ] }
{ aaron: [ { type: 'join', id: 'aaron' } ] }

did aaron replace charlie? how do i spit everyone out?

Comment: this means that somehow you reset the  `var clientMessages = {};` I guess you call that function again for some reason, is that possible? I mean the function that wraps that peace of code. to check this, you can just put a `console.log('resetted');`  below that statement ( `var clientMessages = {};` ) 
If resetted appears more times then means that you call that function many times, if you want you can post the full file so it is easier to fix

Comment: ok it's here: https://github.com/mrtunes/websocket-relay-server/blob/master/index.js and the frontend is in /web

Comment: ok i moved it above, and this line 47 still just logs the number 1 event as new users come on
     console.log(clientMessages[parsed.id].length);

Comment: That is normal, what you want is `console.log(Object.keys(clientMessages).length)` or just print clientMessages

Answer (score 0):

whichever function whats to keep a watch on this object, send them the `clientMessages.length`. This method can then perform the next necessary actions.

Comment: this is along the lines of what i'm looking for, but it's showing up as undefined -   console.log(clientMessages.length);

Comment: ok logging clientMessages[parsed.id].length shows the number 1 even as new users come on. ideally want to see it increment

Comment: I am on it. let me see if i find something